# Https urls in Laravel - Rackspace with Filesystem

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, https, rackspace-cloud, flysystem

I am using filesystem package without problems for upload and download files to rackspace. According to docs on [how to obtain the file url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-urls) I do:

```
$content = fopen('logo.png', 'r+');
\Storage::disk('disk_temp')->put('logos/logo.png', $content);

$url = \Storage::disk('disk_temp')->url('logos/logos.png');
```

Works good. But, this url is `http://` version. How to obtain the secure version like `https://` if I am using rackspace vendor?  Here my config:

```
'disk_temp' => [
        'driver'    => 'rackspace',
        'username'  => env('RS_USER'),
        'key'       => env('RS_API'),
        'container' => 'disk_temp',
        'endpoint'  => 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/',
        'region'    => env('RS_REGION', 'DFW'),
        'url_type'  => 'publicURL',
    ],
```

Years before, I used [Open Cloud](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloudv) successfully, obtaining the URL as

```
$file = \OpenCloud::container('cdn')->uploadObject($filename, $content);
$url = (string) $file->getPublicUrl(UrlType::SSL);
```

Just to know if possible doing the same from laravel itself. Thank you in advance.